# Deleting a large file on R server does not reclaim storage on laptop

Tags: disk, r

I am using R server and I deleted multiple files totaling 40GB. I have a folder on my local disk and created a symbolic link to be able to use the files without uploading them to R server. Any time i need to unzip the file and create it into a parquet file. This leads to 1 file unzipping to 28GB and then after parquet 1.9GB. After I deleted the 28GB file I didn't need but when I go to my settings on my windows laptop, the storage did not decrease after deleting file.

What I understand so far my ubuntu uses a vhdx so storage on it will keep expanding. I tried other options such as disk partition to compact the disk, but that's not a long-term solution. Ive tried all cleaning options through the terminal. All the asnwers i have searched for does not work for me. I don't know what else to do.

You can say that I can just unzip myfile locally, but for me that is not a option either, hence the reason my data folder is mounted from my local laptop to wsl/Rserver.

The only solution I have found is to uninstall and reinstall, but that is not ideal or what anyone would want to do.

Is there any way I can reclaim my disk space?

Comment: Sounds like a Windows Answer but: *"This is accomplished with the `optimize-vhd cmdlet`. The Compact operation is used to optimize the files. This option reclaims unused blocks and rearranges the blocks to be more efficiently packed which reduces the overall size of the VHDX virtual hard disk file.Sep 7, 2023"*

Comment: "You can say that I can just unzip myfile locally, but for me that is not a option either" ... I can't understand what this means/why not. Why can't you unzip the 28GB file on a Windows folder, make a parquet file of it there and move the parquet file to the WSL directory? Then delete the zip file.